# Making a class object from a class in a different cell within the same notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I need to make an object of a class in a different cell

I have a classification project with tensorflow in google colab(a jupter notebook). I have a main class that has an object of the tensorflow model classes are in different cells. How do I do this?

In cell 1 I have:

```
class Model:
```

In cell 2 I have:

```
import Model  # doesn't work 

class Mainprogram:
.
.
.

    def create_model(self):
        self.model = Model(self._Learning_rate, self._epochs, 
                           np.shape(program.train_x),
                           10, [32, 64, 128], strides, pool_size)

program = Mainprogram()
strides = (1, 1)
pool_size = 2
program.train_x, program.train_y, _ = program.read_data()
program.create_model("./train", 0)
```

I want it to import said class , but it looks like the wrong way to do it 
any help ?

Comment: Once you run the first cell, the contents are held in-memory.  There is no need to import.  Also, each cell is not considered a separate file, which would be necessary to use `import`

Comment: thanks , that seems to be it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the cells in the notebook have the same access to all the variables you generated within a session. You have to import the libraries you use only once, and  you don't have to import anything else. You can just run your cells linearly. The variables/functions/classes you use must just be defined before you use them, just like a regular python script.